# difference between x += x and x = x + x in Python list

Tags: python

code first:

```
# CASE 01
def test1(x):
    x += x
    print x

l = [100]
test1(l)
print l
```

`CASE01` output:

```
[100, 100]
[100, 100]
```

that's OK! because l (a list) is mutable.

then,

```
# CASE 02
def test2(x):
    x = x + x
    print x

l = [100]
test2(l)
print l
```

`CASE02` output:

```
[100, 100]
[100]
```

Although the difference still can be understand.
in `x = x + x` way, `x`, at the most left, has been created/assigned as a new one.

but why?

If `x += x` is same with `x = x + x` on definition, but why they have two different achievements？
And how the details go in the two ways?

Thank you!

Comment: *"If x += x is same with x = x + x on definition"*... They're not.

Comment: Your _re_-defining a new local variable `x` in `test2()`.

Comment: When `a` is mutable, `a += b` will mutate `a`. However,  `a = a + b` will _never_ mutate `a`, it will always create a new `a + b` object and bind it to the name `a`. This may be a little surprising, but it is rather convenient. ;) "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. Although practicality beats purity."

Comment: FYI: @PM2Ring's quote comes from the [Zen of Python]https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x += x` is calling `append` under the hood, which mutates the original variable

`x = x + x` is creating a new variable local to `test2` and setting that value, which doesn't affect the original `x`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused what case 2 is really doing. The parameter is not modified. It doesn't matter it's named x, you made a new local variable to the function.

And so you could have also done this

```
def test2(l):
    x = l + l
    print x
```

Where, again, `l` may be the variable outside the function, but it's not the same (well, technically, yes, it's the parameter)

---

By the way, you can also multiply lists.

```
In [1]: [100, 200]*2
Out[1]: [100, 200, 100, 200]
```